# MariaDB query for parent and child category

Tags: mariadb, hierarchical-data, mariadb-10.4

I have this MariaDB table "categories":

```
id  category        parent_id
1   electronics     0
2   fashion         0
3   TV              1
4   mobile          1
5   Sony            3
6   power bank      1
7   iphone          4
```

and I want result using MYSQL Query

```
1 electronics
3 electronics >> TV
5 electronics >> TV >> Sony
4 electronics >> Mobile
7 electronics >> Mobile >> iphone
6 electronics >> Power bank
2 fashion
```

Comment: MYSQL version 10.4

Comment: when am run this SELECT VERSION(); output like 10.4.17-MariaDB

Comment: I think this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: I edited to make it clear you use MariaDB, not MySQL. These two products have diverged enough that we should think of them as different databases with different features.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, category, parent_id, category path
         FROM categories
         WHERE parent_id = 0
       UNION ALL
         SELECT c.id, c.category, c.parent_id, CONCAT(cte.path, ' > ', c.category)
         FROM categories c
         JOIN cte ON cte.id = c.parent_id )
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d9d59ace66a91b6b95c14e31cd1f6d1b